# How to run for loop faster in R when dealing with large dataframe

Tags: r

This is how my data frame looks something like this:

```
  Code-1    Type    Year   Code-2
AB1034510  Type-A   2014   501324
AB1034927  Type-C   2013   501324
AB1039701  Type-B   2012   501325
AB1036802  Type-D   1998   501325
AB1031649  Type-F   2016   501328
```

but this dataframe has about 4.5 million rows with 12 columns.

I was trying to run a for loop so that I can find rows with same Code-2 values and find the oldest year from those rows. And then, assign that oldest year to the rows with the same Code-2 values. So it will look like this:

```
 Code-1    Type    Year   Code-2
AB1034510  Type-A   2013   501324
AB1034927  Type-C   2013   501324
AB1039701  Type-B   1998   501325
AB1036802  Type-D   1998   501325
AB1031649  Type-F   2016   501328
```

to get this procedure done, I tried the code:

```
for (n in 1:nrow(df)) {
  same.code2=which(df[n,4]==df[,4])
  min.year=min(df[same.code2,3])
  df[same.code2,3]=min.year
}
```

But it seems either I have done something wrong or it takes too long to run the code.

Any help pretty please?

Comment: So technically you want to wade through all values of Code-2 and find which row holds the oldest date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `data.table`. It's fast and simple.

```
library(data.table)    
dt <- data.table("Code-1" = c('AB1034510', 'AB1034927', 'AB1039701', 'AB1036802'),
                 Type = c('Type-A', 'Type-C', 'Type-B', 'Type-D'),
                 Year = c(2014, 2013, 2012, 1998),
                 "Code-2" = c(501324,501324,501325,501325))

dt[, Year := min(Year), by = 'Code-2']
```

Data before:

```
      Code-1   Type Year Code-2
1: AB1034510 Type-A 2014 501324
2: AB1034927 Type-C 2013 501324
3: AB1039701 Type-B 2012 501325
4: AB1036802 Type-D 1998 501325
```

And afterwards:

```
      Code-1   Type Year Code-2
1: AB1034510 Type-A 2013 501324
2: AB1034927 Type-C 2013 501324
3: AB1039701 Type-B 1998 501325
4: AB1036802 Type-D 1998 501325
```

Comment: oh btw, can you teach me how things in brackets work? i am not familiar with data.table package...

Comment: The package is well documented. Take a look at `vignette('datatable-intro')`.

Comment: Thank you @akrun ! I must say your reputation made me quite unsure about the results of the benchmarks ;)

Comment: Since I am curious I tried key'ing `Year` first and then evaluate your expression. It is indeed faster then but interestingly still 58% slower than taking the minimum in the first place.

Comment: Is there a way to put two conditions in by? like by=c('Type','Code-2')?

Comment: And it turns out that this did not work out for half of rows that needs adjustments...weird

Comment: @Dr.Jay what do you mean exactly with 'need adjustments'?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[order(Year), Year := Year[1] , by = 'Code-2']
 df
 #       Code-1   Type Year Code-2
 #1: AB1034510 Type-A 2013 501324
 #2: AB1034927 Type-C 2013 501324
 #3: AB1039701 Type-B 1998 501325
 #4: AB1036802 Type-D 1998 501325
 #5: AB1031649 Type-F 2016 501328
```

---

If we need a `dplyr` solution

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>%
   group_by(`Code-2`) %>% 
   arrange(Year) %>% 
   mutate(Year = first(Year))
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(`Code-1` = c("AB1034510", "AB1034927", "AB1039701", 
  "AB1036802", "AB1031649"), Type = c("Type-A", "Type-C", "Type-B", 
 "Type-D", "Type-F"), Year = c(2014L, 2013L, 2012L, 1998L, 2016L
 ), `Code-2` = c(501324L, 501324L, 501325L, 501325L, 501328L)),
 .Names = c("Code-1", 
 "Type", "Year", "Code-2"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: What makes yours more efficient than mine?  And no, I did not down vote your answer.

Comment: @MartinDabbelJuSmelter  You are getting the `min` which should be slower than `order`ing and get the first observation.

Comment: where come the "first" pls ?

Comment: @DimitriPetrenko  It is from the `dplyr`

Comment: @akrun: I did check it and mine is faster.

Comment: akrun-mean: 473.67  martin-mean: 81.66 in nanoseconds for 50000 rows

Comment: No offense @akrun ! Can it be that mine ifaster because I am not using the `i` expression in `data.table`?

Comment: @MartinDabbelJuSmelter  THanks, I had a vague idea from some previous questions I answered that it would be faster.  Anyway, you got it sorted out.  Usually, with using `key`, it would be fast for the subsequent runs.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes, that was me as I had a vague doubt that the other person posted the solution within secs before I posted.  Thanks for clearing that up.